# $f$ - odd implies $d(f)$ - odd, question to the proof

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homology-sphere

I have problem with such a proof, namely, for $f$ - odd function we get the local degree $d(f)$ is odd.
Generaly, we start with $f$ - $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, odd function, then there is a construction concidered a hyperplanes (point is, that we can take such a hyperplane, that non of regular points $\left\{p_1,\ldots p_r\right\}$ = preimages of a regular value $q\in\mathcal{S}^n$. We know also that
$$d(f)=r \ (mod \ 2).$$

Now we define hemispheres, and two maps: $g$ and $\rho$ - they are acutally on the picture. As you see, $\rho$ is odd, and $g$ is as below.

My question is, how from below diagram we can deduce eqaulity (6):
$$d(f)=\underline{+}d(\rho\circ g|_{S^n})$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $d(g)$ is the integer $d$ such that the leftmost map in the diagram $H(g):H(S^n)\to H(S^n)$ is given by multiplication by $d$.  Similarly, $d(\rho\circ g|_{S^{n-1}})$ is the integer $d$ such that the rightmost map $\tilde{H}(\rho\circ g):\tilde{H}(S^{n-1})\to \tilde{H}(S^{n-1})$ is multiplication by $d$.  Now if you choose generators of $H(S^n)$ and $\tilde{H}(S^{n-1})$ and so identify them with $\mathbb{Z}$ and compose all the horizontal maps together to get just isomorphisms from the left all the way to the right, you get a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z} @>{}>> \mathbb{Z}\\
@V{d(g)}VV @VV{d(\rho\circ g|_{S^{n-1}})}V \\
\mathbb{Z} @>{}>> \mathbb{Z}
\end{CD}$$
where the top and bottom maps are both isomorphisms.  An isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ must be multiplication by $\pm 1$.  So commutativity of this square says that $(\pm 1)d(g)=(\pm 1)d(\rho\circ g|_{S^{n-1}})$ for some choice of signs, or $d(g)=\pm d(\rho\circ g|_{S^{n-1}})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)